Ways of selecting $4$ shoes out of $5$ pair to form exactly $1$ pair of shoes
The question is to find the number of ways in which 4 shoes can be selected from 5 pair shoes such that we have exactly 1 pair. 
My try- 
Suppose the five pair of shoes are $ (a_1,a_2)(b_1,b_2)(c_1,c_2)(d1_,d2)(e_1,e_2) $ 
Now I can select any one of the 10 shoes first, then I have to select its pair so I can only select 1 shoe. Suppose I selected the pair $  (a_1,a_2) $, so then I have 8 choices for 3rd shoe. Suppose it is $ b_1$ and since we have to only get 1 pair , I can't choose $ b_2$, so I have 6 choices for last shoe.  Total number of permutations is $ 10 \times 1 \times 8 \times 6 = 480 . $ Now since order in which shoes are selected is not important , I have to divide it by number of ways in which the above 4 shoes can be arranged and that is $ 4! = 24. $ So the answer becomes $ \frac {480}{24} = 20.$ 
But if I try to find it out by other way the answer is coming different. The second way is to first select one pair of shoes out of 5 pair and then select two pairs of shoes from remaning four pairs and choose 1 shoe from both pair i.e. $ ^5C_1 \times ^4C_2  \times ^2C_1 \times ^2C_1 = 5 \times 6 \times2 \times2 = 120.$  Not only both answers are different, there is a huge difference between them. So what went wrong in either of the approach?

Does the sequence in which. the pair appear among the 8 selected matter ? Does it matter whether the left of the pair appears before the right ? Such questions wouldn't be asked were the question about probability where only consistency in counting favourable and total ways matters, but when you are only counting ways, you need to be specific

In your first you insist that the pair be chosen first, so you are not counting all possible orders of the shoes.  You should only divide by $4$, one factor of $2$ for the order of the two shoes in the pair and one factor for the other two shoes.  This makes the two agree.
